# How to configure MySQL Router on two application servers?

Tags: mysql-5.7, mysql-innodb-cluster, group-replication, mysqlrouter

I have three MySQL servers running with group replication and inside a InnoDB Cluster.

I have two app servers that will be connecting to the cluster and I need to configure mysql router on both app servers. When I run router on server1 I use the `--bootstrap` option. When I try to do it on server2 with `--bootstrap` I get an error

> a router instance named has been previously configured on this host.

My question is do I need to start mysql router with `--bootstrap` option? Or since it will be configured on two servers `--bootstrap` option is not required? Do I need to start mysql router with a personalized conf file?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue and I am posting what resolved it for me in case someone else might run into this dilemma.

The resolution was to run mysqlrouter with the --bootstrap option on both app servers but I was missing the --name parameter (which is a bootstrapping option). The --name parameter gives a symbolic name to the router instance and since I was not passing on that parameter it gave it a blank name or ' '. Like ' ' router instance already existed then when trying to bootstrap on server 2 it was failing because ' ' router instance already exited. The trick here is to give each router instance a different name. All the examples that I found online only show you how to configure the router for a single instance not for a double instance that is why I was making the mistake on not giving it a name.

Anyway, I hope this helps someone.